# Are the elements of a set within a set also the elements of the latter?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

It is my understanding that an event is a subset of the set of all possible outcomes (sample space). If however the sample space consists of elements which are sets, can an event be defined as one the elements from these "inner" sets?
Ex. A coin is flipped twice, (S={(H,T),(T,H),(T,T),(H,H)} Is the event A=(H) valid for the sample space despite not being a subset of S?

Comment: $(H,T)$ for example is an elementary element. To calculate its probability , you need the probabilities for $H$ and $T$, But $H$ is not an elementary event of "flipping twice"

Comment: With reference to set theory only, and not probability, the answer is No. If $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{3,4,5\}$, then $\{A,B\}$ has only two elements, and neither of these is an integer in $[1,5]$.

Comment: There are transitive sets, where every element of a set is also a subset of the same set.  These are used in set theory. Each ordinal is an example, but there are others.

Comment: I'm getting the strong impression this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- there is some event you are trying to express, and you've come up with the idea that maybe $(H)$ does so, and you've made the *mistake* of asking the very narrow question of whether $(H)$ makes sense. If this is all true, you'd do better asking if $(H)$ conveys what you're trying to convey, or even just ask your actual problem about how to express the event you want to express!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $\def\T{\mathcal T}\def\H{\mathcal H}$It is my understanding that an event is a subset of the set of all possible outcomes (sample space). If however the sample space consists of elements which are sets, can an event be defined as one the elements from these "inner" sets?
>
> Ex. A coin is flipped twice, $S=\{(\H,\T),(\T,\H),(\T,\T),(\H,\H)\}$ Is the event $A=(\H)$ valid for the sample space despite not being a subset of S?

Well, no $(\H)$ is not an element of the sample space, nor is $\{(\H)\}$ a subset of it.   (Neither are $\H$ or $\{\H\}$ such, respectively.)

*However,* if by $A=(\H)$ you mean such as "the event of the first coin toss being heads", then this *actually* represents the event $\{(\H,\T), (\H,\H)\}$, which is indeed a subset of the sample space.

---

Let $A$ be a *random variable* mapping the sample space, $S$, to the result of the first toss of the coin, symbolically $A:S\mapsto \{\H,\T\}~,~\forall (x,y)\in S ~ [A(x,y):=x]$.

When we write $\mathsf P(A=x)$ we are actually referring to the event, $\{\omega\in S: A(\omega)=x\}$ .

It is convenient shorthand used because we *really don't want* to write the entire set builder notation every time.   It is also somewhat easier to read.

$$\begin{align*}\mathsf P(A=\H) &= \mathsf P\{\omega\in S: A(\omega)=\H\} \\ &= \mathsf P\{(\H,y)\in S:\forall y\in\{\H,\T\}\} \\ &= \mathsf P(A^{-1}(\H))  \\ &= \mathsf P_A(\H)\\&= \mathsf P\{(\H,\T), (\H,\H)\} \\&= \tfrac 12\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

No.

In the first place, if $x\in y$ and $y\in z,$ then in most cases it is not true that $x\in z.$

For example, consider the set $\{\  \{1,2,3\},\  \{2,3,4\}\  \}.$ This set has only two members. If $1,2,3,4$ were members of it, then it would have at least four members.

In the second place, in the set $\{\,(H,T),(T,H),(T,T),(H,H)\,\},$ the pair $(H,T)$ is not a set with members $H$ and $T$; rather it is an ordered pair with components $H$ and $T.$

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can get something close.  When you're looking a series of outcomes like that, the sample space is the product space of the sample space of each individual experiment.  Here, for example, your sample space is $\{H,T\}^2$, and if $\pi_i(a_1, \ldots, a_i, \ldots, a_n) := a_i$ is the $i$-th component function, you can arbitrarily define the event $E = \pi_1^{-1}(H)$ to get the event you're looking for.

More importantly, this set is well-behaved, meaning you can always find its probability (i.e. in terms of measure theory, it's measurable with respect to the product sigma algebra).

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider {{1}}, whose only element is {1}. 1 is an element in {1} but not in {{1}}.